# My Emmet is not working in VS Code for .php file

Tags: emmet, abbreviation

I can't understand why my emmet is not working in index.php file but it still working index.html file , I mean .html file when I'm usually type ! then press TAB KEY From Keyboard ! Is there anyone can solve this issue.

Show Expanded Abbreviation
Shows expanded Emmet abbreviations as suggestions. The option "inMarkupAndStylesheetFilesOnly" applies to html, haml, jade, slim, xml, xsl, css, scss, sass, less and stylus. The option "always" applies to all parts of the file regardless of markup/css.

always